# Is there a way to add a global annotation for all domains?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa

I want the annotation below to be the default for all of my domain objects.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

Rather than adding this manually to every domain class, I was wondering if there is a way to make this the default for all domains.

I am working with spring-boot application that utilizes Gradle for builds and JPA and Hibernate for persistence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java supports way to inherit annotation of super type if the annotation applied to super type is annotated with a meta annotation `@Inherited` [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html).

But since the `@JsonInclude` annotation is not annotated with `@Inherited`, I think you'll have to add it manually to your domain classes.

Answer (score -1):

You can make one `SuperClass` annotate the same with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` and extend it, like below:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class SuperClass {

}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{

}
```

Comment: Super class annotation is only applied to sub classes when the annotation itself is annotated with `@inherited`. I think this will not work.

Comment: I think @barunsthakur  is correct about "inherited".  If this worked it would have saved having to add the imports and the annotation but it is also not appealing to have extend the superClass in every domain.  Thank you for the suggestion.